# What does the '#' character (number sign) mean in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Javascript and I'm try to understand some code. I don't understand and I can't find any documentation about the `#` sign.

```
$(function () {
      $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
```

What does $("#searchTerm") mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Note: This answer doesn’t doesn’t start from the premise that the question is asking about jQuery. The addition of the jQuery tag and title edit were not done by the person who asked the question, and who accepted this answer).

In JavaScript? Nothing special. It is just part of a string.

The `$` function might do something with it, but [it is hard to tell what the `$` function is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting).

There are a lot of libraries which provide a `$` function that acts as a kitchen sink for that library. They include [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). This one looks most like jQuery, in which case the argument is a string containing a [CSS selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), so the `#` indicates the start of an [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

This "Selects a single element with the given id attribute".

Comment: I'm gonna assume `$` is jQuery.

Comment: I'd also include a pointer to the [W3 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#overview) as a good overview of all selector types.

Comment: it is jQuery on a first look...  good answer but the 'what is the $ symbol' discovery journey is over the top and unnecessary - maybe at 100K+ things look different...

Answer (score 47):

Now # would/could mean private instance fields: https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-fields/

**2021 update:**

> Class fields are public by default, but private class members can be
> created by using a hash # prefix. The privacy encapsulation of these
> class features is enforced by JavaScript itself.

```
class ClassWithPrivateField {
  #privateField;
}

class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod() {
    return 'hello world';
  }
}

class ClassWithPrivateStaticField {
  static #PRIVATE_STATIC_FIELD;
}

class ClassWithPrivateStaticMethod {
  static #privateStaticMethod() {
    return 'hello world';
  }
}
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: Is what version(s) of JavaScript is this supported? (Adding this information to the answer could help make it more complete.)

Comment: @JonSchneider - It's still an in-progress proposal, though I'd be surprised if private instance fields aren't in ES2021.

Comment: **The code in the question makes it clear this is not what the OP is asking about** (despite this answer technically being a valid answer for just the title of the question, ignoring its content).

Comment: While this may not address the OP's question, some will nevertheless find this question on SO when searching for information about JavaScript identifiers prefixed with **#**. I had no clue about the prefix's function, so I was grateful for this answer.

And FWIW, the link that @celsown provides has been superseded by this one: [ECMAScript Class features proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/unified.html)

Comment: `#` is not only a prefix given to private instance fields but also [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) as well. They are solid part of the language since Chrome v74, Edge v79, Node v12, Deno v1 etc...

Answer (score 17):

That's jQuery and the pound sign (#) refers to an element's ID. It's one way jQuery can select an element. In your example, it would select the element with the ID of "searchTerm".

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function
>   document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another
>   selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery
>   performs an additional check before identifying the element as a
>   match.
>
> As always, remember that as a developer, your time is typically the
>   most valuable resource. Do not focus on optimization of selector speed
>   unless it is clear that performance needs to be improved.
>
> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior
>   should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.
>
> If the id contains characters like periods or colons you have to
>   escape those characters with backslashes.

See: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 4):

That's just a string.  The `#` is just part of a string.  I'm assuming the `$` is jQuery.

That means, that the string is a jQuery selector (or rather a CSS selector).  The `#` means "ID".  It's searching the DOM for the element with the ID `searchTerm.

Answer (score 3):

With the given information, it is most likely the jQuery ID selector

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 2):

That's the id selector for elements in HTML (in the DOM to be specific).

Answer (score 2):

It's an element ID e.g: `...

When u need to access this div with JS or jQuery just call it `$("#xyz")`.do something

for class `<div class="abc">....</div>` >> `$(".abc")`

Answer (score 0):

That isn't vanilla Javascript! That's jQuery!

In jQuery you can select elements via CSS style selectors. In this case, `#x` is a CSS selector to select all elements with the id `x`.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. It doesn't stop being JavaScript.