# what is # symbol functinality, in angular while interpolating value

Tags: angular, typescript

from this link, https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks the foll. example is given

```
export class PeekABoo implements OnInit {
  constructor(private logger: LoggerService) { }

  // implement OnInit's `ngOnInit` method
  ngOnInit() { this.logIt(`OnInit`); }

  logIt(msg: string) {
    this.logger.log(`#${nextId++} ${msg}`);
  }
}
```

In this example, I do not understand, what # symbol does here. I referred angular documentation, it says # is used to create refs. but this is not form or any field to create ref.

Comment: Might this be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899448/what-does-the-sign-mean-in-javascript ? I'm not up-to-date in Angular, but perhaps it's of the same sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example `#` is a character in a log line and is used as [number sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign).

It has no special meaning here and shouldn't be confused with Angular [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars).